# Finding closed expression for the output of an LTI system

Tags: signal-processing

I'm having a problem with two exercises. Dealing with LTI systems, how can I get the analitic expression of the output in a closed form of these two problems? Can someone help me?

*1st problem:*

$$y[n] − 0.4y[n − 1] = x[n]$$ $$y[−1] = 1$$

$$x[n] = 0.4^n u[n] \ \mathrm{for} \ n = −5, ..., 30$$

*2nd problem:*

$$y[n] − 3y[n − 1] + 2y[n − 2] = x[n] − 2x[n − 1]$$

$$x[n] = (1/3)^n u[n] \ \mathrm{for} \ n = −5, ..., 30$$